# Android How do I add icons to action bar?

Tags: android, menu, icons, android-actionbar

I want to know how I can add a icon to the action bar, just like in the example link below from Android market?
Please come with example codes.

[Example picture](http://i45.tinypic.com/2uonnk3.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's not the title bar.. try looking for `ActionBar`

**EDIT:**
here is an example to create your own action bar
[action bar example](http://appfulcrum.com/2010/08/29/simple-actionbar-for-android-application/)

Comment: I have changed my question now